# Installing Linux Library on Windows Using Mingw

Tags: linux, windows, installation, mingw, msys

I am attempting to install [GTKExtra](http://gtkextra.sourceforge.net/cms) on windows. The package comes in a `Tar.Gz` and contains a `Configure` file. So its necessary to install the package using [MinGw](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) because the package is designed to be installed on Linux.

I have installed MinGW and MSYS. I have made sure that C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\etc\fstab contains the line `C:\MinGW   /mingw` (plus an empty line below it).

**My Problem:** I still cant get windows run the `Configure` file. When I type in `./Configure` into CMD I get the error `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

The steps I am taking are:

- Open cmd.exe
- Navigate to the folder that contains the `configure` file using `cd C:/...`
- Type in `./configure` (as per the instructions found in `INSTALL`. But this causes the error I described above

How can I run the `configure` file on windows? What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run the command in unix command prompt. For starting unix command prompt execute "msys.bat" in msys installation.

Comment: To be more clear: I need to run "msys.bat" found in C:\MinGW\msys\1.0